# How to pre-fill the Orbeon text field based on selection on radio button

Tags: forms, if-statement, calculated-columns, orbeon

I am creating an Orbeon form. There is a radio button (`control-114`) field and a text field (`control-111`).

- radio button has two value 1 and 2 (string input)
- if value 1 is selected, text field is empty (allowing user to fill)
- if value 2 is selected, text field is per-populated with 'xxx-xxx-xx'

I tried the following syntax in the calculated value:

```
 if($control-114='1') then $control-111='1' else ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there with that expression! In the "Control Settings", "Formulas", "Calculated Value" for `control-111` (the text field), you'll want to have:

```
if($control-114 = '2') then 'xxx-xxx-xx' else .
```

Also, in "Read-Only", you should mark the field explicitly as *not read-only*, with the following, otherwise fields with a "Calculated Value" automatically become read-only.

```
false()
```

Comment: thank you so much! That really helped again! concept clear to make sure that calculated value always make the field Read only.